# Cartesian product over real numbers and axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we consider the integers, it is possible to form sets
$$
C=\{(\ldots,0,n_i,0,\ldots):n_i\in\mathbb{Z},\;n_i\text{ is in the $i^{th}$ slot}, \text{ and }0\text{ in every other slot}\}
$$
with the additional requirement that if $(\ldots,0,m_i,0,\ldots),(\ldots,0,n_i,0,\ldots)\in C$ have integers in the $i^{th}$ slot, then $m_i=n_i$. For example, one possible $C$ is just the set $\{(\ldots,0,i,0,\ldots):i\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ is in the $i^{th}$ slot}\}$.

Can we do this with larger sets? For example, with $\mathbb{R}$? My overall goal is to have a set of tuples $(\ldots,0,r,0,\ldots)$ with $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that every real number $r$ appears exactly once. That is, for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$, we can find a corresponding tuple $(\ldots,0,r,0,\ldots)$, and if there are two tuples $(\ldots,0,r_1,0,\ldots),(\ldots,0,r_2,0,\ldots)$ such that $r_1,r_2$ are in the same slot, then $r_1=r_2$.

My first thought is that this is impossible, for cardinality reasons. I don't know much about the axiom of choice, but can it be applied here to make this construction? I know that if you assume the axiom of choice, you can well-order the reals. Can I make use of this? Or is this just impossible?

Comment: An $X$-tuple of elements of $\mathbb{R}$ is just a function $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ (you can think of an ordered pair as a function $f\colon\{1,2\}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $f(1)$ is the first coordinate of the pair, and $f(2)$ is the second coordinate of the pair). So all you want is the function $f_r\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that has $f_r(s) = 0$ if $r\neq s$, and $r$ if $r=s$; and then take $C=\{f_r\mid r\in\mathbb{R}\}$. However, you cannot think of the $\mathbb{R}$-tuples as “lists” or “sequences” as you are writing them.

Comment: Okay thanks. That is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t do it with sequences, since $\Bbb R$ is uncountable. What you *can* do is define for each $r\in\Bbb R$ the function

$$f_r:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
r,&\text{if }x=r\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and let $C=\{f_r:r\in\Bbb R\}$. Then for each $r\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ the function $f_r$ is the unique member of $C$ that has $r$ in its range, and $f_r(x)=0$ if $x\ne r$. This is entirely analogous to the set of doubly-infinite sequences $\left\langle n_k^{(m)}:k\in\Bbb Z\right\rangle$ for $m\in\Bbb Z$, where

$$n_k^{(m)}=\begin{cases}
m,&\text{if }k=m\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

The axiom of choice doesn’t enter into it unless you want to choose the non-zero values of the functions $f_r$ in some fairly exotic way.